# Is there an open source PDF printer written in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, pdf, printing, driver

I want to look at the source code of a PDF printer to see how they do the printer driver part, but so far I've only found PDF Creator which is written in VB. There are plenty of freeware PDF printers but they're not open source, and I need to look at the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the project [EmfPrinter](http://emfprinter.sourceforge.net/) written in C++.

Answer (score 1):

I use [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) to convert Word documents to PDF.

I believe the source code is available.

If you really only want the "printer driver" part then this may not be what you're looking for. But if you're interested in the PDF generation then it may very well be.